# Is there something like Low Reorder just for Categories?

Tags: categories, low-reorder

I'm in the process of taking things out of our codebase and into content where they belong, things like navigation and listings of categories. I really enjoy the features offered up by the [Low Reorder](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-reorder) add-on. I use [Draggable](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/draggable) to manage the order of categories within a category group, but I would only need a subset of these categories.

E.g. given a category group of:

- Alpha
- Beta
- Carrot
- Doc
- Elephant
- Mouse

I may just want 3 of those in a custom order in one place, 4 of them in a different order in another, but all I'd need are the category names, url_titles, and in the desired sequence. Don't need entries. Just the categories.

I might just go ahead and make a channel just for entries with 1:1 relation to categories (maybe along with a [WB Category Select](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wb-category-select) field as the relation) and then use Low Reorder to create subsets as desired. But I really want to avoid having to essentially enter content twice and any overhead of channel:entries when all I really need is a list of category names and url_titles. I suppose a bonus would be getting to using the entry title over the category name as an option or something.

I could add custom fields to the category group(s), but then you wouldn't be looking at the set in front of you.

Before I set off to do this I figured I might as well ask the community if there is anything like Low Reorder just for categories? Or if there's an existing module, add-on, or method to do this that slip passed me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up using [Taxonomy v3](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/taxonomy).

I was thinking of going the "easy" route of just using existing channels and using Low Reorder in a somewhat ad-hoc basis... but a few things occurred to me which I was neglecting:

- `{exp:channel:entries}` is expensive. Better to avoid it.
- Every time I add a new entry it would still be added to a set which is made worse if there are multiple sets to a channel.

All I really needed was a way to make simple, customizable lists that preferably tied *directly* to categories and/or entries. Tying things to categories doesn't seem to exist, so perhaps a way to match url_titles and mentioning the category group id somewhere.

Going through devot-ee I narrowed my options down to [NavEE](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/navee) and Taxonomy. NavEE is really simple and looks like it'd help get the job done, but for $10 more Taxonomy offers further customization via custom fields. I kind of dislike having to refer to trees via their id as opposed to some kind of text reference as it's just easier code-wise between development and other versions of a site... but it's got enough features for my needs.

To simulate a list of categories I make a new tree and add custom links where the link is the category's url_title. If needed I can add a custom field to mention which group the category is in. <del>The "tricky" part is that using the `{exp:taxonomy:nav display_root="no"}` tag results in outputting</del> To avoid an unordered list e.g. `<ul>...loop thru nodes...</ul>` use `style="linear"` (haven't tried this yet, hat tip to @iain urquhart).

<del>To work around it hypothetically you could use stash's list methods. I didn't spend a whole lot of time on it but I couldn't get `{exp:stash:set_list}` to work if it was wrapping it, but perhaps append_list inside of it would work. What I ended up using was either [surgeree](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/surgeree)'s `strip_tags` method or stash get's strip_tags parameter.</del>

To get actual category data I use [Cat2](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cat2), I have my own [fork](https://github.com/notacouch/cat2) that I can get custom field stuff. ...should have probably added a way to get the images, too...

In the end the one caveat that comes to mind is that if you change an url_title of a category, you'd have to change this everywhere you have used it manually. May want to refer to the category's id instead of url_title if that is an issue.

Now if I could just learn to cache instances of taxonomy and its results... and just cache in general... but that's another topic.

Comment: Hey, you can use style="linear" in taxonomy:nav to prevent the list HTML/wrappers being output, that allows you to use whatever HTML you want.

Comment: @IainUrquhart Don't have time to try this just yet but added it to the answer anyway. Thank you!